# Inner Join Right Approach for this Query?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I would like some help with an SQL query that I am struggling with, Ive got 90% of what I need it to do done its just the last bit that I'm having a little issue with.

## Database Design

I have the following database Schema

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEES(
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    SEX CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    COST INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SKILLS(
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SKILL VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_SKILLS(
    EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SKILL_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PROFICIENCY SET('1','2','3','4') NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID,SKILL_ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX(SKILL_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILLS(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROJECTS(
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    LOCATION VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    INCOME INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TASKS(
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DATE_FROM DATE NOT NULL,
    DATE_TO DATE NOT NULL,
    COMPLETED BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,

    FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECTS(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TASK_SKILLS(
    TASK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SKILL_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PROFICIENCY_REQUIRED SET('1','2','3','4') NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(TASK_ID,SKILL_ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX(SKILL_ID,TASK_ID),

    FOREIGN KEY (TASK_ID) REFERENCES TASKS(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SKILL_ID) REFERENCES SKILLS(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ASSIGNED_TO(
    EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TASK_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DATE_ASSIGNED DATETIME NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID,TASK_ID),
    UNIQUE INDEX(TASK_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID),

    FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (TASK_ID) REFERENCES TASKS(ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

## Query

So the query that I would like to create would be to return every `EMPLOYEE` within the database along with their `SKILLS` and the `PROFICIENCY` of their skill. This was the part of the query where I had no trouble with and I have the following query:

`SELECT EMPLOYEES.ID, CONCAT_WS(' ',EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME,EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME) AS NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(SKILLS.SKILL),EMPLOYEES.COST,GROUP_CONCAT(EMPLOYEE_SKILLS.PROFICIENCY)
FROM EMPLOYEE_SKILLS
JOIN EMPLOYEES ON EMPLOYEE_SKILLS.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEES.ID
JOIN SKILLS ON EMPLOYEE_SKILLS.SKILL_ID = SKILLS.ID
GROUP BY EMPLOYEES.ID`

The above query gives me the majority of what I want, where it returns every employee within the database and their associated skill and the level that they know it at.

The thing that I am struggling with now is that I would also like to join up this query to also look into the `ASSIGNED_TO` table of the database as well, where I would like to find all the employees within the organisation (assigned to a task or not) and return the `TASK` ID that they have been assigned and the start and end date of said task.

Ive tried simply adding another join to the `ASSIGNED_TO`table within the above query but it doesn't give me the desired output. I'm suspecting because I am grouping by the employee id. Would I need to use something like two queries to get what I want, for example and inner select and an outer select and do an inner join between them? Not really sure what the approach would be for this query.

Sorry for the long post and any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Will an employee always be assigned to at least one task? Then inner join is ok, otherwise you'd want an outer employee->assigned_to join, and then an innner join assigned_to->task ...

Also if you only want one row per employee you may want to look into GROUP_CONCAT() for merging all assigned tasks into a single textual list column in the result

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It kinda makes sense. Im my case an EMPLOYEE can be assigned to more than one task, so I guess I will have to take the second option that you have mentioned. Im not really sure how inner and outer joins work and what kind of syntax would be required to have two separate statements and joining them with either an inner or outer join. Thanks

Comment: Inner joins join every row from the first table to every row on the 2nd. Just saying `JOIN` or explicitly saying `INNER JOIN` is the same.

A `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will join every row from the 1st table to every matching row of the 2nd, but if there is no matching 2nd table row you'll still get 1st table row once while pretending that there is a matching 2nd table row with all fields having a `NULL` value. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is the reverse: all rows from 2nd table, and if no matching 1st table row add NULLs.

Comment: Ah Great thank you so much, I just tried it now and it worked! Forever grateful!